# Integrating leadbolt notification ad

Tags: android, leadbolt

I am very novice at programming. I am trying to integrate leadbolt notification advertising in to my android app. I followed the directions that they have and got stuck. The instruction is

Add the notification service registration code:
This is achieved by adding the following code inside your onCreate()
function (or inside the function where you wish to trigger the
notification).

```
    AdController myController = new AdController(getApplicationContext(),
    "MY_LEADBOLT_SECTION_ID");
    myController.loadNotification();
```

Where exactly do i add it? do i put it under template.java?

Answer (score 1):

Please add the code inside the onCreate() function in your main Activity java class.